# Save route as image bing maps

Tags: javascript, angular, bing-maps

I developing an Angular app that tracks a users journey in bing maps (I have to use bing)

When the journey is complete, I would like a way to save the journey as an image to display, at a later time.

I understand I can generate an image using the rest services, but if, for instance, the user returns to view a route years from now, and roads have been changed, would that not mean the route itself would  be different?

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify departure date time in the route request. If you request a new route next year with a date/time set to today, you should get the same route as you would if you were to request one right now. Note that saving the responses from Bing Maps services (other than geocoding) is against the terms of use.

Comment: Great answer thanks, the thing as well is do you know of a work around to get more than 25 waypoints in a static map as my route will have more

Comment: The only way to do that would be to retrieve a blank static map, georeferenced it, then use drawing tools to draw the line on top. A decent amount of work. I've done this before years ago using the old SOAP version of the services, but haven't had time to update it to use the REST services. You can find the post here: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/ve-imagery-service-and-custom-icons/

https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/ve-imagery-service-polygons-and-polylines/

Comment: This was the way I was going to plot the journey using the v8 api, however, polylines don't snap to roads, they will go through building across fields etc

Comment: You can pass the waypoints into the routing service when needed and it will generate a polyline that follows the road.